# Resizable is causing other elements below it to move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable, resizable

I am building a UI where I need to have two or more resizable and draggable DIVs.
The problem that I am facing is that when you resize a div all the other divs that were originally below it are moving(changing their position). Please see https://jsfiddle.net/2f8g93nn/4/ where I wrote an example of what I mean. In that example if you moved the second div to the right and resized the first div the position of the second div will change.

HTML in jsfiddle.net:

```
<!doctype html>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="Element" id = "FirstDiv"  class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>First DIV</p>
</div>
<div class="Element" id = "SecondDiv" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Second DIV</p>
</div>
```

Javascript in jsfiddle.net:

```
   $(function() {
    $( ".Element" ).draggable();
     $( ".Element" ).resizable();   
  });
```

CSS in jsfiddle.net:

```
.Element { 
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border:1px solid black; 
}
```

[image: At the begining Second div is below first div]

[image: We moved the second div to the right]

[image: By increasing the size of the first div the position of the second div changed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my opinion and make thing simple, why don't you use  tag...

Here is the Demo code: https://jsfiddle.net/SeokKuan/2f8g93nn/8/

```html
 <textarea  style="height: 100px;" placeholder="First Content"></textarea><br>

<textarea  class="form-control" style="height: 100px;" placeholder="Second Content"></textarea>
```

nn/8/

Comment: I did not get that ? can you explain more

Answer (score 1):

You should use `position: absolute;` for elements which should be placed independently into the page

https://jsfiddle.net/2f8g93nn/5/

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend use CSS attribute

```
position:absolute
```

But you have to rearrange the elements after loading, otherwise they will overlap.
I made a quick jsfiddle example for this:
https://jsfiddle.net/hanno_drefke/2f8g93nn/9/

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I came up with and it worked is by adding:

```
$('.ui-resizable').removeClass( "ui-resizable" )
```